# yii2 .htaccess subdirectory route is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

my htaccess configuration in the root directory looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
```

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|images|blog)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ frontend/web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ frontend/web/blog/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js|blog)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

in frontend/web looks like

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
RedirectMatch 404 /composer\.
RedirectMatch 404 /.bowerrc

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

everything works fine with images,css,js (for example, path site.com/images works correctly) except "/blog" page, after click on menu button, app redirects me to "site.com/frontend/web/blog" instead of "site.com/blog"
im using yii2 NavBar widget

```
$menuItems = [
  ...
       ['label' => 'Blog', 'url' => ['/blog/index'], 'options'=>['class'=>'font-menu']],
```

url manager rules

```
        'rules' => [
            'blog/<url>/<category_id>' => 'blog/one',
            'blog/<category_id>' => 'blog/category',
            'blog' => 'blog/index',
```

don`t understand how to fix it, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution this way

in main-local config

```
    'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => '',
    ],
```